# How to swap a portion of a uwp xaml interface with another on the same page and modify controls?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So I have a user interface which has several controls which I want to persist. One of these controls is a button that is supposed to swap between a view and an edit mode. Each of these will have many controls in them that will need to be accessible later on. My main page is defined as follows, with irrelevant stuff stripped down of course.

MapView.xaml

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TripPhotoMapper"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
    x:Class="TripPhotoMapper.MapView"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="grid_main">

        <Maps:MapControl x:Name="map_main" MapTapped="MapUserTapped"/>

        <StackPanel x:Name="stack_edit_mode">
            <Border Tapped="ButtonEditMode">
                <TextBlock Text="Edit Mode"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="grid_swap_interface">
            here is where I want the swapable interfaces
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MapView.xaml.cs

```
namespace TripPhotoMapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MapView : Page
    {
        private EditMode _mode_edit;
        private ViewMode _mode_view;
        private Control _mode_current;

        public MapView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            _mode_edit = new EditMode();
            _mode_view = new ViewMode();
            _mode_current = _mode_view;

            grid_swap_interface.Children.Add(_mode_current);
        }
        public static class GlobalVars 
        {
            ...

            //this keeps track on if we are in edit mode
            public static bool glo_edit_mode = false;
        }

        ...

        private void MapUserTapped(MapControl sender, MapInputEventArgs args)
        {
            ...

            //this is the problem
            ViewMode.txtblc_view_mode.Text = "hi";
        }

        //editing controls
        private void ButtonEditMode(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            grid_swap_interface.Children.Clear();
            if (GlobalVars.glo_edit_mode == false)
            {
                _mode_current = _mode_edit;
            }
            else
            {
                _mode_current = _mode_view;
            }
            grid_swap_interface.Children.Add(_mode_current);
        }
    }
}
```

I then have two other very barebones xaml files for the two interfaces.

EditMode.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TripPhotoMapper.EditMode"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TripPhotoMapper"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <Button/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewMode.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TripPhotoMapper.ViewMode"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TripPhotoMapper"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtblc_view_mode" Text="view mode"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I haven't touched the C# for either of these two additional xaml's yet. So they're just like this.

EditMode.xaml.cs

```
namespace TripPhotoMapper
{
    public sealed partial class EditMode : UserControl
    {
        public EditMode()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

So I've figured out how to swap between the two interfaces without any issue; the button and textblock do both appear as they should. However, I included (for testing) a function to change the text in txtblc_view_mode to "hi", but I'm given the following error:

'ViewMode.txtblc_view_mode' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I'm incredibly new to splitting up files like this and I can't figure out how to fix it. I've found something mentioned in a few posts

```
x:FieldModifier="public"
```

but I don't know where to put it. Could anyone help me? Once the interfaces are properly split up, a lot of controls in each will have to be modified in code and thus I'll need to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can't try this for now but you can check it out.

Add/modify the following code in your ViewMode cs:

```
public sealed partial class ViewMode : UserControl
{
    public static ViewMode Current { get; private set; }

    public ViewMode()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Current = this;
    }
}
```

And maintain the `x:FieldModifier="public"` in your desired control (TextBlock) to be edited/modified.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtblc_view_mode" x:FieldModifier="public" Text="view mode"/>
```

On EditMode cs, add in your methods:

```
public void ChangeTxtBlockText()
{
    TextBlock tb = ViewMode.Current.txtblc_view_mode as TextBlock;
    if (tb != null)
    {
       tb.Text = "Hi";
    }
}
```